# How to replace a value of a variable with string

Tags: perl, replace

I have a variable called `$test=0` and `$test1=1`. I need to replace this values as `$test="false"` and `$test1="true"` whereever the value of `$test=0` and `$test1=1`.How can I do this.

Comment: You should know that `0` is already false and `1` already true. By changing the value to the strings, you are making both values true (as far as Perl is concerned). The only difference is that true/false is human readable.

Comment: I'm generating a report, for which I need to replace the value of the variables.

Comment: In that case, I would do something like `print $test ? "true" : "false"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `do`. It is used to loop through a designated block of code while a specific condition is evaluated as true.

```
do { $_ = $_ ? 'true' : 'false'; } for $test, $test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Regex :)

```
if ($test =~ m/\d/ ) {
    $test = "false";    
}
if ($test1 =~ m/\d/ ) {
    $test = "true";    
}
```

or `Scalar::Util::looks_like_number()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple for loop:

```
for ($test, $test1) {
    $_ = $_ ? "true" : "false";
}
```

If `$_` is true, the ternary operator returns the string `"true"` and vice versa. The return value of the ternary operator is assigned to `$_`. The variables are aliased to `$_` inside the loop, so the original variables are changed.